# How to create a singleton Toast in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs6.2

I need to create a single toast on the screen of my application, today if I click multiple times on a button, several toasts are presented.

EDIT:

```
showToast: function(message) {
    var openedToast = Ext.get(document.querySelector('[id^="toast-"]'));
    if (openedToast != null) {
        var toast = Ext.getCmp(openedToast.id);
        toast.close();
    }
    Ext.defer(function() {
        Ext.toast({
            html: message,
            align: 't'
        });
    }, 80);
}
```

But if the user clicks the button quickly, the toast is created several times

Comment: Need way more specifics than this. Post some code, created a plunkr if possible, talk about what you've tried, what is the expected behavior, etc.

Comment: But what exactly you want to do with other toasts (If you want to display multiple toasts at once)? Just ignore or remove previous toast and show new one or...?

Comment: I need to remove previous toast. See the edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give it a unique identifier and check if it already exists before creating a new one.

```js
{
    xtype: 'button',
    handler: function(){
        if(!Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myToast').length){
            Ext.toast({
                itemId: 'myToast',
                html: 'toast!'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/215n)